# Automatic selection between static_cast and dynamic_cast for best performance

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, static-cast, virtual-inheritance

I have to use an object factory that creates new objects of several types each of which is derived from the polymorphic base class. The type of each object is known beforehand, but the factory returns the pointer on the base class. So after construction I need to downcast that pointer to the type of specific object class. In most situation `static_cast` does its job perfectly, but in the case of virtual inheritance `dynamic_cast` must be used for downcasting. At the same time I do not want to use `dynamic_cast` for simple types with not-virtual inheritance from base class due to its run-time overhead.

In other words, I would like to find or make a function that will convert `From`-type into `To`-type using `static_cast` if it is available for this conversion (e.g. `To` is not *virtually* derived from `From`) or `dynamic_cast` otherwise.

Expected use case:

```
template <typename To, typename From>
To fastest_cast( From && from );

struct A { virtual ~A() = default; };
struct B : A {};
struct C : virtual A {};

int main()
{
    B b;
    fastest_cast<B*>( (A*)&b ); //expected static_cast inside

    C c;
    fastest_cast<C*>( (A*)&c ); //expected dynamic_cast inside
}
```

Is there anything similar to `fastest_cast` in std-library or in boost-library? Or it is necessary to implement the conversion function by myself (please suggest how)?

Comment: It's a valid question, and there may be a way. But it's also worth noting that, if you're doing this for performance reasons, it may be misguided. You're sacrificing the safety of `dynamic_cast` (namely, the runtime check) for the perceived efficiency of skipping it. And, in my mind, if you're worried enough about efficiency that the type of cast is at issue, you probably shouldn't be using virtual inheritance in that part of your program to begin with.

Comment: This doesn't make seance. `static_cast` in code says: I know what type it is just do conversion at compile time. `dynamic_cast` says: I suspect this type check this at runtime. If you need this strange `fastest_cast` you do not understand difference or you do something strange in code.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd expect static_cast to be used in the first situation.  There's no guarantee that the `A*` is a `B*`, it could be some other class derived from A.

Comment: And compilers will likely already optimize this given static analysis. This should be easy to verify on Godbolt https://godbolt.org/

Comment: A `static_cast` expression is plain ill-formed when casting `A*` to `C*`. It's not too hard to SFINAE on that. It's also possible to make this behave differently in Debug and Release mode. Might not be a pointless venture if you have good test coverage.

Comment: Re: "`To` is not virtually derived from `From`" -- that is **one** of the cases where you need `dynamic_cast`. Another one is when you don't know if a pointer to `From` in fact points at an object of type `To`; `dynamic_cast` will give you a null pointer if the conversion can't be done. And the third is casting **across** a hierarchy: `struct B1 { virtual `B1`(); } struct B2 { virtual ~B2(); } struct D : B1, B2 { }`'. Now if you have a `D` object named `d` you can write `B1*b1ptr = &d;` and `dynamic_cast<B2*>(b1ptr)`.

Comment: @Eljay: The idea here is not to use `dynamic_cast` for checking, but only for its more complicated address adjustment.  The `static_cast` case obviously relies on somehow knowing the dynamic type of the object—but here one wouldn’t necessarily check the `dynamic_cast` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The concept [`std::derived_from`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/derived_from) seems to cover the case where you want `static_cast`, we just have to remove the reference or pointer for it.

```
template <typename To, typename From>
concept castable = (std::is_pointer_v<To> && std::is_pointer_v<std::remove_cvref_t<From>>) || (std::is_reference_v<To>)

template <typename From, typename To>
concept castable_from = std::derived_from<From, std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_pointer_t<To>>> || std::derived_from<From, std::remove_cvref_t<To>>

template <typename To, castable_from<To> From>
To fastest_cast(From&& from) requires castable<To, From>
{
    return static_cast<To>(from);
}

template <typename To, typename From>
To fastest_cast(From&& from) requires castable<To, From>
{
    return dynamic_cast<To>(from);
}
```

Comment: How does this address virtual inheritance?

Comment: Is there a reason why compiler implementations don't already do this optimization? It feels a bit like people writing obscure code like "a << 2" because "it's faster than `a * 4`". I wouldn't second guess the compiler unless I had solid reason.

Comment: (For the record, I upvoted for instructive answer - the technique is insightful regardless of question merit)

Comment: @sehe because the `static_cast` isn't safe here. It is UB if you get it wrong